# How to fix code that is outputting 2 lines instead of one using if statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, ifstream

My code compiles and when I run it and enter a number, then it will output 2 lines of code instead of one. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my if-statement that is causing it. But I want to know what it causing my program to output 2 lines instead of 1 with if-statements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double weight;

    cout << "Enter the weight of your package: ";
    cin >> weight;

    ofstream sout, mout, lout;
    sout.open("shiprates_small.txt");
    mout.open("shiprates_medium.txt");
    lout.open("shiprates_large.txt");

    if (sout.is_open())
    {
        if (weight >= 1 || weight < 10)
        {
            sout << "Shipping rates: " << endl;
            cout << "Go see shiprates_small.txt " << endl;
        }
        sout.close();
    }
    if (mout.is_open())
    {

        if (weight >= 10 || weight < 30)
        {
            mout << "Shipping rates: " << endl;
            cout << "Go see shiprates_medium.txt " << endl;
        }
        mout.close();
    }

    if (lout.is_open())
    {
        if (weight >= 30)
        {
            lout << "Shipping rates: " << endl;
            cout << "Go see shiprates_large.txt " << endl;
        }
        lout.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output

```
Enter the weight of your package: 9
Go see shiprates_small.txt
Go see shiprates_medium.txt
```

Comment: `if (weight >= 10 || weight < 30)` 9 is less than 30. Perhaps you want to use `&&` in these comparisons.

Comment: Alright thanks for correcting my mistake. I forgot about that flaw when using Or operators. Switching it to `&&` did the job and my code now works.

Comment: I am older than 100 years OR I am younger than 2 million years.

Comment: Thanks for the example and thanks for editing my code to make it look cleaner paddy. I was able to solve my question with using **and** operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the or `||` with and `&&`

`if (weight >= 1 && weight < 10) {// der code}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and correcting my mistake with the if-statement. I accepted this as an answer :).